# Difference between `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` and `sales_order_place_after`?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

Once user placed an order I would like to send SMS alert to user.

When I look for event, I found `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` and `sales_order_place_after`.

Operationally, they both doing same I believe. Is there any difference between these two? Which one should be used in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`** event fire whenever *checkout/onepage/success* page is rendered *** ,other wise it does not fire***

And **`sales_order_place_after`** fire whenever we call  [Mage_Sales_Model_Order](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1113) object's function `place()`  called. And its call **`totally depends on payment  mathods configuration`***

From my point of view it will better to use **`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`** ,use of after order payment ,you may be want  to fire sms.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use observer for sales_order_place_after action. Because it depends if order create on the admin panel